# Pass java compiled file as an argument to an ant target

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to use [Daikon](http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon/) to test a large project so I needed ant to compile and run everything for me. Since I'm new to ant I'm trying to get familiar with it through a simple example given to Daikon. So, the best candidate example is the associated StackAr package with Daikon.

To run Daikon normally I will execute the following command after compiling all the java files I'm targeting.

```
java daikon.Chicory --daikon DataStructures.StackArTester
```

which is equivalent to this command

```
java -cp "/usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/daikon.jar:." daikon.Chicory --daikon DataStructures.StackArTester
```

Both commands will run `daikon.jar` using `Chicory` interface with the flag `--daikon` and will take the `StackArTester.class` to instrument it and run it.

Now, my attempt to run the same command using ant looks as the following:

```
<project name="StackAr" default="compile" basedir=".">
  <description>
    simple example build file
  </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="DataStructures"/>
  <property name="build" location="DataStructures"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac  srcdir="${src}" 
            destdir="."
            debug="on"
    />
  </target>

  <target name="run" description="run StackArTester">
      <java classname="DataStructures.StackArTester">
         <classpath>
             <pathelement location="."/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
  </target>

  <target name="inv" description="run daikon">
      <java classname="daikon.Chicory" >
         <arg value="--daikon" />
         <arg value="DataStructures.StackArTester"/>
         <classpath>
             <pathelement path="/usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/daikon.jar"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up">
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
  </target>
</project>
```

The target `compile` is used to compile all the source files and is working. Also, the target `run` is used as a test to run the targeted .class file and is working. The target `inv` is where I'm having trouble and it's suppose to be equivalent to the two command above.

My issue is that I'm not sure how I'm suppose to pass the .calss file to Daikon. From the results I have seen I'm positive that first argument/flag `--daikon` is recognized. However, for the second argument `DataStructures.StackArTester` in most of my tires I see that it's recognized, but Daikon has an issue with its classpath. Runing the script above `ant inv` will generate the following error message:

```
Buildfile: /usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/examples/java-examples/StackAr/build.xml

inv:
     [java] 
     [java] Executing target program: java -cp /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/daikon.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar -ea -Xmx1000m -javaagent:/usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/java/ChicoryPremain.jar=--daikon --dtrace-file=StackArTester.dtrace.gz DataStructures.StackArTester
     [java] entered daikon.chicory.Runtime.setDtrace(./StackArTester.dtrace.gz, false)...
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class DataStructures.StackArTester
     [java] Chicory warning: No methods were instrumented.
     [java] Warning: Did not run Daikon because target exited with 1 status
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Note that the error is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class DataStructures.StackArTester
```

I'm out of ideas about what I might try. Hopefully the information above is enough. Please note that I'm in the same directory when executing the original commands and the ant command.

Thakns ...

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
 [java] Error: Could not find or load main class DataStructures.StackArTester
```

means that Java did not find the class `DataStructures.StackArTester` on your classpath.

On the line that starts with `[java] Executing target program`, the `-cp` command-line argument is your classpath.  The classpath must contain a directory or jar file containing `DataStructures/StackArTester.class`.  You just need to augment the classpath.

Comment: Hello Michael, first thank you for your support on both Google group and here. I'm aware that the the issue is with the classpath (my bad that I didn't make this clear), my issue is how to add it to the build script. I think I have tried all the obvious ways to do it. For example it tried to add it just like what I did for daikon's jar e.g. `<pathelement path="/usr/lib/daikonparent/daikon-5.2.20/examples/java-examples/StackAr/"/>` also `<pathelement location="."/>` since the class is in my current directory. None of these work. Even more, none of these will show any affect on the shown `-cp`

Comment: [UPDATE] I solved the issue, but it doesn't make sense to me how it was the cause. I was lazy and didn't set up daikon's jar on my `CLASSPATH`. And because I was out of ideas I thought I should cross that off my list. Now it works, but the reason I'm saying it doesn't make sense because I still need to specify the path for daikon's jar in ant's build script. Taking it off will generate an error of not finding `daikon.jar` even though it's specified on my `CLASSPATH`.